# How can I write a loop or adopt other strategies to reduce these codes?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

following, I have some samples of my data:

```
sample <- tibble::tibble(
    asbr15 =c(45.8,53.5,58.8,58.8,45.8,45.8,45.8,45.8,78.9,50.3,46.7,46.7,45.8,58.8,45.8,53.5,58.8,46.7,46.7,46.7),
asbr16=  c(176,205.6,179.4,179.4,176,176,176,176,186.3,167.4,159.3,159.3,176,179.4,176,205.6,179.4,159.3,159.3,159.3),
asbr17=  c(42.88,50.38,60.15,60.15,42.88,42.88, 42.88,42.88,80.69,50.05, 45.93,45.93, 42.88, 60.15, 42.88, 50.38, 60.15,45.93,45.93,45.93),
u_parameter= c(38.00,46.50,41,43,38,36,40,36, 46.50, 31,23,  23, 40, 45, 40,46.50, 42.00, 22, 21, 22.00))
```

I have written some codes by which I can calculate what I need; however, they are not so user-friendly. Thus I want to reduce these codes. My codes are as follows.

```
library(dplyr)
sample<-mutate(sample, f_curve_tilde_age15       =asbr15)
    sample<-mutate(sample, f_curve_tilde_age15.25= asbr15*0.75+asbr16*0.25)                 
    sample<-mutate(sample, f_curve_tilde_age15.5 = asbr15*0.50+asbr16*0.50)                     
    sample<-mutate(sample, f_curve_tilde_age15.75= asbr15*0.25+asbr16*0.75)                    
    sample<-mutate(sample, f_curve_tilde_age16   = asbr16) 
    sample<-mutate(sample, f_curve_tilde_age16.25= asbr16*0.75+asbr17*0.25) 
    sample<-mutate(sample, f_curve_tilde_age16.5 = asbr16*0.50+asbr17*0.50)   
    sample<-mutate(sample, f_curve_tilde_age16.75= asbr16*0.25+asbr17*0.75)

    ### then

    sample$f_curve_notched_age15   <-ifelse((sample$u_parameter + 0.75 < 15.00),0, 
    sample$f_curve_tilde_age15)
    sample$f_curve_notched_age15.25<-ifelse((sample$u_parameter + 0.75 < 15.25),0, 
    sample$f_curve_tilde_age15)
    sample$f_curve_notched_age15.5 <-ifelse((sample$u_parameter + 0.75 < 15.50),0, 
    sample$f_curve_tilde_age15)
    sample$f_curve_notched_age15.75<-ifelse((sample$u_parameter + 0.75 < 15.75),0, 
    sample$f_curve_tilde_age15)
    sample$f_curve_notched_age16   <-ifelse((sample$u_parameter + 0.75 < 16.00),0, 
    sample$f_curve_tilde_age15)
```

Since these codes are supposed to continue until the upper ages, they do not seem to be efficient. therefore, I need to reduce them by writing a loop or a function to improve efficiency. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a somewhat similar approach as @AndS: this data will be easier to work with in long format. Since the main task here is linear interpolation, I think we can take a simpler approach.

First I add a row number to help keep track of where we started from. This might not be necessary if the `u_parameter` values are always distinct, but if we add a row we don't need to keep track of this. Then I reshape longer, putting the column name into a column called "age", and parsing the number in it (I want "15" not "asbr15").

Next, I "complete" the ages to include all numbers from 15 to 17 in 0.25 increments. This creates new rows with `NA` in the `f_curve_tilde` variable. We can use `zoo::na.approx` to perform the linear interpolation based on the available values and ages, within each original row of data.

Finally, we can use a formula to calculate the `f_curve_notched` values.

This results in a long-formatted table, which should lend itself well to further analysis and/or visualization. If you want to report it in wide format, then we can add a `pivot_wider` step at the end.

```
library(tidyverse)
sample |>
  mutate(row = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(-c(row, u_parameter), 
               names_to = "age", names_transform = parse_number,
               values_to = "f_curve_tilde") |>
  complete(nesting(row, u_parameter), age = seq(15, 17, 0.25)) |>
  arrange(row, age) |>
  mutate(f_curve_tilde = zoo::na.approx(f_curve_tilde, age),
         f_curve_notched = f_curve_tilde * (u_parameter + 0.75 < age),
         .by = row)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 180 × 5
     row u_parameter   age f_curve_tilde f_curve_notched
   <int>       <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>           <dbl>
 1     1        38    15            45.8               0
 2     1        38    15.2          78.4               0
 3     1        38    15.5         111.                0
 4     1        38    15.8         143.                0
 5     1        38    16           176                 0
 6     1        38    16.2         143.                0
 7     1        38    16.5         109.                0
 8     1        38    16.8          76.2               0
 9     1        38    17            42.9               0
10     2        46.5  15            53.5               0
# ℹ 170 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

If we add this at the end, we get a wide table:

```
... |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = age,
              values_from = c(f_curve_tilde, f_curve_notched),
              names_vary = "slowest")
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 20 × 20
     row u_parameter f_curve_tilde_15 f_curve_notched_15 f_curve_tilde_15.25 f_curve_notched_15.25 f_curve_tilde_15.5 f_curve_notched_15.5
   <int>       <dbl>            <dbl>              <dbl>               <dbl>                 <dbl>              <dbl>                <dbl>
 1     1        38               45.8                  0                78.4                     0               111.                    0
 2     2        46.5             53.5                  0                91.5                     0               130.                    0
 3     3        41               58.8                  0                89.0                     0               119.                    0
 4     4        43               58.8                  0                89.0                     0               119.                    0
 5     5        38               45.8                  0                78.4                     0               111.                    0
 6     6        36               45.8                  0                78.4                     0               111.                    0
 7     7        40               45.8                  0                78.4                     0               111.                    0
 8     8        36               45.8                  0                78.4                     0               111.                    0
 9     9        46.5             78.9                  0               106.                      0               133.                    0
10    10        31               50.3                  0                79.6                     0               109.                    0
11    11        23               46.7                  0                74.9                     0               103                     0
12    12        23               46.7                  0                74.9                     0               103                     0
13    13        40               45.8                  0                78.4                     0               111.                    0
14    14        45               58.8                  0                89.0                     0               119.                    0
15    15        40               45.8                  0                78.4                     0               111.                    0
16    16        46.5             53.5                  0                91.5                     0               130.                    0
17    17        42               58.8                  0                89.0                     0               119.                    0
18    18        22               46.7                  0                74.9                     0               103                     0
19    19        21               46.7                  0                74.9                     0               103                     0
20    20        22               46.7                  0                74.9                     0               103                     0
# ℹ 12 more variables: f_curve_tilde_15.75 <dbl>, f_curve_notched_15.75 <dbl>, f_curve_tilde_16 <dbl>, f_curve_notched_16 <dbl>,
#   f_curve_tilde_16.25 <dbl>, f_curve_notched_16.25 <dbl>, f_curve_tilde_16.5 <dbl>, f_curve_notched_16.5 <dbl>, f_curve_tilde_16.75 <dbl>,
#   f_curve_notched_16.75 <dbl>, f_curve_tilde_17 <dbl>, f_curve_notched_17 <dbl>
```

Comment: Nice! I knew there was a better way to do the final pivot. Thanks for teaching me something new.

Comment: I face this Error on my real data:
 Problem while computing `f_curve_tilde = na.approx(f_curve_tilde, age)`.
✖ `f_curve_tilde` must be size 16770 or 1, not 16746.

Comment: Hmm, that's tricky to diagnose without any details about your data. Perhaps you have rows with `NA` in `age` at that step, which could arise if some of the pivoted columns didn't have numbers in them? Maybe you could try `|> count(age) |> view()` just after the `arrange` step?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my thought process for something like this. I see that you are holding some of the info in the column name. When I see this, my fist thought is "we need to pivot  longer". This will get the info out of the column names and into its own column, making it easier to do computations. The next thing I see is that you you have 4 computations per group, so we need to expand the rows to take this into account. Then, I would compute the variables you are interested. Lastly, all we need to do is clean up the column names and pivot the whole thing wider.

```r
library(tidyverse)


sample_df |>
  mutate(row = row_number())|>
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('asbr'),
               names_to = "asbr", 
               names_pattern = "asbr(\\d+)", 
               names_transform = as.numeric) |>
  mutate(amount = list(c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75))) |>
  unnest_longer(amount) |>
  arrange(row, amount) |>
  mutate(f_curve_tilde_age = value*(1-amount) + lead(value)*amount, .by = c(row, amount))|>
  mutate(f_curve_notched_age =  ifelse(u_parameter +0.75 < asbr + amount, 0, f_curve_tilde_age[amount ==0]),
         .by = c(row, asbr))|>
  mutate(name1 = map2_chr(asbr, amount, ~paste0("f_curve_tilde_age", .x, substring(.y, 2))),
         name2 = map2_chr(asbr, amount, ~paste0("f_curve_notched_age", .x, substring(.y, 2)))) |>
  filter(!is.na(f_curve_tilde_age)) |>
  (\(x) {
    list(
      select(x, row, u_parameter, starts_with('f_curve_tilde'), name1) |>
        pivot_wider(names_from = c(name1), values_from = c(f_curve_tilde_age)),
      select(x, row, u_parameter, starts_with('f_curve_notched'), name2) |>
        pivot_wider(names_from = c(name2), values_from = c(f_curve_notched_age))
    ) |>
      reduce(full_join, by = c("row", "u_parameter" ))
  })() 
#> # A tibble: 20 x 18
#>      row u_parameter f_curve_tilde_age15 f_curve_tilde_age16
#>    <int>       <dbl>               <dbl>               <dbl>
#>  1     1        38                  45.8                176 
#>  2     2        46.5                53.5                206.
#>  3     3        41                  58.8                179.
#>  4     4        43                  58.8                179.
#>  5     5        38                  45.8                176 
#>  6     6        36                  45.8                176 
#>  7     7        40                  45.8                176 
#>  8     8        36                  45.8                176 
#>  9     9        46.5                78.9                186.
#> 10    10        31                  50.3                167.
#> 11    11        23                  46.7                159.
#> 12    12        23                  46.7                159.
#> 13    13        40                  45.8                176 
#> 14    14        45                  58.8                179.
#> 15    15        40                  45.8                176 
#> 16    16        46.5                53.5                206.
#> 17    17        42                  58.8                179.
#> 18    18        22                  46.7                159.
#> 19    19        21                  46.7                159.
#> 20    20        22                  46.7                159.
#> # i 14 more variables: f_curve_tilde_age15.25 <dbl>,
#> #   f_curve_tilde_age16.25 <dbl>, f_curve_tilde_age15.5 <dbl>,
#> #   f_curve_tilde_age16.5 <dbl>, f_curve_tilde_age15.75 <dbl>,
#> #   f_curve_tilde_age16.75 <dbl>, f_curve_notched_age15 <dbl>,
#> #   f_curve_notched_age16 <dbl>, f_curve_notched_age15.25 <dbl>,
#> #   f_curve_notched_age16.25 <dbl>, f_curve_notched_age15.5 <dbl>,
#> #   f_curve_notched_age16.5 <dbl>, f_curve_notched_age15.75 <dbl>, ...
```

This may look more verbose than your current code, but what you gain is flexibility. This code takes care of any number of ages that might be in your real dataset. Admittedly, the `(\(x) list(...)()` structure at the end could probably be condensed to a single call to `pivot_longer`, but I was feeling lazy and didn't want to dig through all the parameters. Also, I changed the name of the data from `sample` to `sample_df` because I don't like to name data as the same name as functions that I use regularly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and the time you devoted. However, my programming skills are not great; therefore, I have a problem comprehending the codes since I need to modify these codes so that they can calculate these amounts for all ages from 15 to 49.

Comment: You do not need to modify anything. The code will automatically canulate these amounts for any ages. Did you try it on your real data? If so, what were the error?