# how write codes In R to calculate specific sequence in R for specific age

Tags: r, function, loops, data.table, mutate

I have a dataSet as follows:

```
     library("tidyverse")
     DataSet2<-
     tibble(
     id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
     AGE=  c(15,15.25,15.5, 15.75, 16, 16.25, 16.5, 16.75, 46.5, 46.75),
     f_curve_notch= c(25.14,30.28,43.33,43.33,25.14,25.14,25.14,25.14,67   
     ,33.77),
     f_curve_tilde= 
                  c(.2514,30.28,43.33,43.33,25.14,25.14,25.14,25.14,.67   
     ,33.77),
      )
```

I want to calculate the ensuing formula in R for 1 million individuals: The first and last formula differs from other groups.

```
    age15probarea=((f_curve_notch(age15)*2)+ 
    (f_curve_notch(age15.25)*2)+f_curve_notch(age15.5)/5.

    age16probarea=(f_curve_notched(age15.5)+ 
    (f_curve_notch(age15.75)*2)+ 
    (f_curve_notch(age16)*2)+ 
    (f_curve_notch(age16.25)*2)+f_curve_notch(age16.5)/8.
     ......
```

This procedure has to continue to 46.5 although I provide information just for some age
and for the last age,

```
       age47probarea=(f_curve_notch(age46.5+ 
       (f_curve_notch(age46.75*2))/3.
```

In the next step: I want to calculate this formula with a condition in which if f_cureve_nutched of a specific age is greater than zero and not equal to f_curve_tilde of the same age then f_curve_tilde - f_curve_notched else be the previous amount for age16probarea:

```
    DataSet$age16probarea<-   ifelse ((f_curve_notch(age15.5)>0 
    &  f_curve_notch(age15.75) != f_curve_tilde(age15.75),
    age16probarea+ ((f_curve_tilde(age15.75) - 
     f_curve_notch(age15.75))*0.125), age16probarea)
```

Comment: This seems like a related, if not the same, question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77029088/how-can-i-write-a-loop-or-adopt-other-strategies-to-reduce-these-codes/77029644#77029644

Comment: Dear @JonSpring, thank you for your comment. Yes, this question is related to that but a continuation of the previous procedure. I am writing codes to calculate birth histories for women, and step by step ask questions about the procedure. However, this question has some differences from the one you have mentioned

Comment: Hi Azam! Your tibble doesn't run, because there are duplicate names

Comment: Also, just double checking - is `age15probarea` meant to be divided by 8? It seems like you are doing a weighted average, but obviously the weighted average is going to be thrown off if there are 5 points in the first one, but it is divided by 8

Comment: @Mark, I don't know exactly but your point seems logical. I am trying to create a curve mentioned in this article:
https://www.jstor.org/stable/2174407?seq=3
 Figure 1

Comment: Coding up each age with a custom formula sounds like a recipe for mistakes and labor-intensive maintenance. Like with the prior question, I'd highly recommend you rethink your approach so your calculations can be applied to all ages at once instead of with 46 different handwritten formulas.

Comment: @AzamMirzaei your code references columns for individual ages, e.g. f_curve_notched_age18.5, but your sample dataframe does not have this

Comment: @mark, f_curve-notched continues utilil age 46.5 and for 1.5 million women. This is just  a small sample. AGE refers to each age of f_curve-notched.

Comment: I really think pivoting the data longer so you have one notched column and one tilde column is the way to go. Otherwise you will have to resort to strange and buggy code which will have to be copy and pasted 50 times over, for each age. And then what if it doesn't work, and you have to change it? Editing 50 code blocks again. It's not good for your sanity Azam, nor good coding practice

Comment: I think I'm confused by this. There appears to be _functions_ `f_curve_notched` and `f_curve_notched_` that are called on (say) `f_curve_notched(age15)` and `f_curve_notched_(age15.25)`, and there appear to be fields like `f_curve_notched_age15.5`, none of those are defined anywhere. Azam, it's unclear to me what you're trying to do, and your question has the components of a reproducible question but too many missing parts to be sufficient.

Comment: Dear @
r2evans I fixed the problem. I have just one "f_curve_notch" and one f_curve_tilde

Comment: You reduced the problem, but we still don't know how the `f_curve_notch` ***function*** is defined. (Or are you thinking it's subsetting or similar?)

Comment: No, it is not a function, it is a column in Dataset. f_curve_notch_(age15.25), "f_curve_notched" that belongs to age 15.25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for lead function:

```
     DataSet2<-DataSet2 %>%
     mutate(prob = (f_curve_notch + 2 * lead(f_curve_notch) + 2 * 
     lead(f_curve_notch, 2) + 2 * lead(f_curve_notch, 3) + lead(f_curve_notch, 
      4))/8) %>%
      as.data.frame()
```